# Get Elements (Countries, Cities etc) from Google Map By View

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to get the Elements from a Google Map by a current viewport?

Example, given following view:

[image]

Now Google Maps API should return: "Nicaragua, Costa Rica, Colombia, Venezuela, Ecuador, etc.". Basically all countries and, in this example, states of Brazil like "Amazonas, Acre, Mato Grosso, etc.". Capitals like "Caracas, Bogota, Quito, etc." are shown in the current view as well so they should be returned, too.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You've tagged this with both the Android API and the Javascript API tags... which one are you using?

Comment: I would use the Javascript API but I guess if this feature is available for one platform it's available for each other, too?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [VisibleRegion](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion), which makes it possible to get the coordinates of your screen.The problem lies with the coverage of your search. It is too large and there is no direct solution that is available in the documentations. The search that would yield the largest result is the [Radar Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#RadarSearchRequests) in Google Places API, which would yield 200 search results in a maximum 50000 meters(radius).